# Why are the outputs of this C code different when formatting with %c and %d

Tags: c, printf, ascii, string-formatting, format-specifiers

Take a look at the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
  int i;

  for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
  {
    printf("%d", i);
  }
return 0; 
}
```

The output is: **`48495051525354555657`**
But if you change `printf("%d", i);` to `printf("%c", i);` the output becomes: **`0123456789`**

Shouldn't both output **`48495051525354555657`** Why are the outputs different when substituting `d` with `c`?

Comment: @Bathsheba is it, though? According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), `%c` expects an `int` which is then converted to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Blaze: If I'm wrong, please answer, I'll upvote if I stand corrected!

Comment: with '%c' you are passing the ASCII value of the corresponding characters (in your case it is numbers from 0-9 while with '%d' you are printing number directly

Comment: @Bathsheba ha, someone ninja'd me. :) To be honest, I also thought it would be UB until I looked it up.

Comment: `"%d"`-> `"%d "` and the output will be somewhat clearer

Comment: Also try `for (i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++) printf("%d:%c ", i, i);`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm grateful for the understanding that y'all've provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because with `%c` the `i` is interpreted as a character and if you look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see that `48` represents the character `'0'`, `49` is `'1'`, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. What that means is when using `%c` `printf()` converts `i` to its ACII codes whereas %d just prints the decimals. Is that right Eraklon?

Answer (score 6):

`%d` prints out a number and `%c` a character. The ASCII codes for 0-9 are 48-57, so it prints those numbers as characters.

Answer (score 2):

In C when you want to print something you need to provide format specifier. Then the compiler will print the things accordingly.

According to your question `%d` specifier is for printing number and `%c` is for printing character.

So when you tried printing integer value using `%c` format specifier then the system is converting `48-57` in char type and that is `'0'-'9'`. And if you go further it will print

> : ; < = > ? @ A B C and so on.

And this is because system follows ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

%d is format specifier for signed integers whereas %c is format specifier for charecters .
let i=48 when %d is used it prints the integer (prints 48).
but when %c is used the 48 is taken as ASCII value and 0 is printed for 48
ascii values
0 = 48
1 = 49
.
.
.
soon
hope you understand press the upvote.  :) ;)